# Is $\sin^2 x$ uniformly continuous on $\mathbb R$?

Tags: real-analysis

Is $\sin^2 x $ uniformly continuous on $\mathbb{R} $ ? I think it might be because it is really similar to $\sin( x) $

Comment: Use the periodicity.

Comment: Or, if you know calculus, use the fact that the derivative is bounded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, every continuous periodic function $\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ is uniformly continuous.

Comment: Proof outline for OP: consider the restriction to the closure of a fundamental domain. As a continuous function on compact set, we get uniform continuity. By periodicity, we may use the same $\delta$ for each $\epsilon > 0$ on all of $\mathbb R$ that we used on the restriction.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x \not =y$, reals.

$|\sin ^2 x -\sin^2 y| = $

$|\sin x - \sin y||\sin x+\sin y| \le $

$2|\sin x -\sin y| = 2| \cos t||x-y| \le$

$2|x-y|.$

Choose $\delta =\epsilon/2$

Used : MVT

$\sin x -\sin y = (x-y) \cos t$, where

$t \in (\min (x,y), \max (x,y)).$